# Javascript typeof Typeahead returns undefined

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, typeof

I'm loading the bootstrap Typeahead plugin prior to calling Typeahead in my script, but typeof Typeahead return undefined even when it's absolutely loaded.

Javascript file line 2650:

```
!function($){"use strict";var Typeahead=function(element,options) // ... rest of plugin
```

Javascript file line 2765:

```
alert(typeof Typeahead);
```

alerts undefined

why would this be the case?

Comment: because `Typeahead` is a private variable in another function...

Answer (score 0):

You don't really show us enough of the code.  But, if the:

```
alert(typeof Typeahead);
```

is outside of the function block where `var Typeahead = function() {...}` appears, then you are outside the scope where that variable (and thus function) is defined so the variable will be `undefined`.  Variables are only visible within the scope in which they are defined.

If you want `var Typeahead` to be available outside that function block, then it must be declared at a higher scope.

As an example:

```
function foo() {
   // define local variable only visible within function foo
   var greeting = "Hi";
}

console.log(typeof greeting);   // will show "undefined"
```

---

```
// define higher scope variable visible in foo and outside of foo
var greeting = "Hi";

function foo() {
    console.log(greeting);      // will show "Hi"
}

console.log(greeting);          // will show "Hi"
```

Comment: Typeahead is loaded in the global scope and alert(typeof Typeahead) is loaded within $(document).ready(function(){});

Comment: @VinceKronlein - your code shows `Typeahead` being defined inside the `!function($) {...}()` function.  That is NOT the global scope.  That's inside a function scope.  If you want more detailed help you will show enough code to show the entire scope of both relevant pieces of code because this question is entirely about scope, yet you've abbreviated your code so it's hard for us to know exactly what is what beyond the fact that `Typeahead` is defined within a function.